# Getting error "Illegal Command: qbasic.exe" on dosbox after successful installation on ubuntu

Tags: dosbox

I installed Dosbox on my ubuntu machine by using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install dosbox
```

After installation, when I open dosbox by typing the following command

```
dosbox
```

in terminal. It opens. After that, I mount a working folder which is already created using

```
mount c /home/myname/qbprogs
```

Where qbprogs is the directory already created by me as a working directory. After that, I change my directory by typing

```
c:
```

So, that is I get the prompt. C:>. After this, if I type the following

```
qbasic.exe
```

I get the following error.

```
Illegal Command: qbasic.exe
```

I have tried searching the internet but did't get any solution to this. Please help.

Comment: Do you still have this problem? Can you try using [DOSBox Staging](https://dosbox-staging.github.io/) and type `dir` or `ls` command after switching to virtual drive C: ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the qbasic.exe file is not in the directory you are mounting. Either find the qbasic.exe file and save it in that directory (in this case your qbprogs directory) or following the below steps.

Download the olddos.exe file from the following link:

http://www.pcxt-micro.com/download.html

After downloading it just copy it to your working directory. (here qbprogs) and then open terminal and type

```
dosbox
```

After that, mount your working folder using

```
mount c /home/myname/qbprogs
```

After that, change the directory by typing

```
c:
```

After this instead of directly typing command qbasic.exe, first install oldox.exe by following command

```
olddos.exe
```

After installation. Use

```
qbasic.exe
```

and it will work.